# How to assign a random colour for each item in an array?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, colors

I have javascript code written to get a random colour from a list of colours:

```
const colours = [blue[800], green[500], orange[500], purple[800], red[800]];
const colour = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
```

In my JSX code I render an image with a random colour

```
{this.state.data.map((n, i) => {
    return (
    <Avatar style={{backgroundColor: colour}}>{n.author.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}</Avatar>
    );
})}
```

The issue I am having is that every object rendered will be the same random colour e.g. orange. What I want to achieve is that each item rendered will have a different colour but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const colours = [blue[800], green[500], orange[500], purple[800], red[800]];
const getColour = () => colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];

{this.state.data.map((n, i) => {
   return (
    <Avatar style={{backgroundColor: getColour()}}> 
      {n.author.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}
    </Avatar>
   );
})}
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
{this.state.data.map((n, i) => {
   // move this line here
   const colour = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];

    return (
    <Avatar style={{backgroundColor: colour}}>{n.author.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}</Avatar>
    );
})}
```